# Promiseのthenメソッドは第2引数を指定しなくても、promiseが棄却済となった場合には必ず呼ばれるのでしょうか？

Tags: ecmascript-6

**catchメソッドの動作確認中、`Uncaught (in promise)` になりました**
※但し、catchメソッドでエラー自体の捕捉は出来ています

**質問**
・Promiseのthenメソッドは第2引数を指定しなくても、promiseが棄却済となった場合には必ず呼ばれるのでしょうか？
・`Uncaught (in promise)` って何ですか？
・JavaScriptエラー？ それともブラウザが独自実装している警告？
※ブラウザはChromeです

---

```
"use strict";
hoge = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    reject('テスト')
})
hoge.then(function (m) {
    alert(m);
})
hoge.catch(function (e) {
    alert("catch")
    alert(e)
    alert("catch")
})
```

Uncaught (in promise) テスト

---

```
"use strict";
hoge = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    reject('テスト')
})
hoge.catch(function (e) {
    alert(e)
})
```

エラー発生しない

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Promiseのthenメソッドは引数を省略した場合でも、コールバック関数が暗黙的に設定されます。これはEcmascript6の仕様で、ブラウザの独自実装ではありません。

このコードは、

```
hoge.then(function (m) {
    alert(m)
})

hoge.catch(function (e) {
    alert("catch")
    alert(e)
    alert("catch")
})
```

これと等価です：

```
hoge.then(function (m) {
    alert(m)
}, function (e) {
    throw e
})

hoge.then(function (m) {
    return m
}, function (e) {
    alert("catch")
    alert(e)
    alert("catch")
})
```

thenメソッドの第2引数を省略した場合、Promiseがrejectされるとデフォルトで引数がthrowされます。`Uncaught (in promise)`が表示されるのはこれが原因です。

---

コメントへの補足:

シーケンスの途中で発生したエラーをまとめて処理したいときは、第二引数を省略して最後にエラー処理を行うことができます。

```
hoge = Promise.resolve('test')

hoge.then(function (m) {
    alert(m);
    return 'test1'
}).then(function (m) {
    alert(m);
    return 'test2'
}).then(function (m) {
    alert(m);
    throw 'error'
}).then(function (m) {
    alert(m);
    return 'test3'
}).catch(function (m) {
    alert(m);
})
```

Comment: thenメソッドの第2引数を省略する場合は「第1引数で指定した関数」でエラー処理を適切にしないといけない、ということでしょうか？　thenメソッドの第2引数を省略するのは例えばどんな時？　エラー発生しない前提？　第2引数を省略することで得られるメリットって例えば何が挙げられるでしょうか？

Comment: @re9 第2引数を省略するのは主にthenを連結するような場合です。エラーが次のthenに継承されるので、最後にまとめてエラー処理を行うことができます。回答にも少し補足を追加しました。